# Linq statement : Order by

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a list of objects that are returned from a web api request. Each object has a Field named "PlaceNo" which can have a value of 0 to n , or -1 if a value have not been assigned.

I need to order the list based of PlaceNo, where it need to be 0 to n , followed by all the -1.

```
allreports.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PlaceNo)).ToList();
```

The current code gives all the -1 at first, then followed by 0 to n.

**Note:** I am doing the type conversion on PlaceNo, becuase the number is passed as string rather than an integer.

Comment: the cleanest way would be to separate them in two lists, order the positive ones, and concat them

Comment: @Dr.Stitch. BY removing the conversion, it sorting does not work at all. I have just tested it.

Comment: sorry, i deleted my comment since i misread your question. i agree with pomber.

Comment: @pomber : Thanks for the suggestion. I definitely have that in mind but I was wondering if I could do it straight using just one LINQ statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The correct way to solve this problem is to do an order-by-then-by query.** Though the suggestion of the other answers -- to convert negative numbers to the maximum int -- will likely work, the best practice is to write the code so that it actually represents the operations you are trying to capture in the code. In this case you have *two* sort criteria, so you should have *two* sorting criteria in the query!

What you want to do is first do an order-by on "is the integer -1?"  That is, order on a *Boolean* quantity. The default ordering is that false comes before true, so if you want the -1's to be sorted last, check to see if the integer is equal to -1.

That should be your order-by clause. The then-by clause is then your normal ordering -- by the integer value.

```
var query = from report in allreports
            let place = Convert.ToInt32(report.PlaceNo) 
            orderby place == -1, place 
            select report;
var list = query.ToList();
```

Make sense?

Comment: Aww.. Here I was about to piggy back off your answer. Here's a code sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eoxZxA Pretty similar, but a little different.

Comment: @Eric performance wise, how do you think this is faster or slower than comparing to Int32.MaxValue as in my answer below

Comment: @SirajMansour: You've got the code written both ways. If you want to know which is faster, **run them** and then you'll know!

Comment: @EricLippert Wow ! Someone forgot to take their daily chill pill. If i wanted to run them i wouldn't have asked for an opinion obviously !.

Comment: @SirajMansour: Do you believe that I or anyone else has some mysterious ability to tell how fast code runs without running it? Performance is an empirical discipline, not a theoretical one.  The value of a guess about which of two things is faster is worth what you paid for it; nothing at all.

Comment: @EricLippert not to drag this on. On the other hand one could predict the cost of their algorithms before writing code, its part of software engineeing. For example in my code, there will be the cost of conversion and comparison to (-1) in every iteration i am guessing. while i don't have enough knowledge to tell if the LINQ statement you wrote will iterate twice over the collection because of the 'then by', someone as Eric Lippert probably would, and that would be a nice piece of information for me to learn. So.. there was a good reason for my question.

Comment: @SirajMansour: You've spent more time typing the comment saying that you're not going to run the code than it would have taken you to run the code. I'm not sure why you're resisting getting an answer to your question.

Comment: @EricLippert true and funny but still avoided dissecting your approach. Cheers :D

Comment: @EricLippert : Thank you, I works perfect and its fast.

Comment: @Libin: If you prefer to use method syntax, use `OrderBy` with `ThenBy`.  This decision won't impact performance (query syntax compiles into method calls).

Answer (score 2):

```
allreports.OrderBy(x => {
  var placeNo = Convert.ToInt32(x.PlaceNo);
  return placeNo == -1 ? Int32.MaxValue : placeNo;
}).ToList();
```

This code is untested i just wrote this off the top of my head so feel free to correct any compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
allreports.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PlaceNo) < 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : Convert.ToInt32(x.PlaceNo));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the performance would be affected but you convert the integer twice.